# Registering Spark API Token

Tags: laravel, laravel-spark

I have created a Spark API Token and am trying to register spark token using this command

> spark register token-value

but I am getting an error

> Cannot open source file register.ada

Does anyone have an idea on what might be causing this error on ubuntu O.S?

Answer (score 1):

You need to buy Spark to get the api token. When you have it, replace `token-value` with your api key.

Comment: You can create a Token under Settings. What you need to buy is the License. I thought Spark was opensource, but clearly its not.

Answer (score 0):

This solved it for me which was required removal of Adacore Spark https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/spark/cant-find-registerada-when-tried-to-register-spark-api-token

Comment: pls provide the important informations in your answer and not just answer with a link as the link could change